# Ionic display webpage

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am creating a social media like app and I need to display my facebook and twitter feed pages inside tabs, issue I'm facing with using the InAppBrowser plugins that it opens the whole site as a page, instead i need it inside the tab when the user switches to it.

My html code:

```
<ion-toolbar no-border-bottom>
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="trendingSection">
  <ion-segment-button value="facebook" (ionSelect)="segmentChanged($event)">
    Facebook
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="twitter" (ionSelect)="segmentChanged($event)">
    Twitter
  </ion-segment-button>
```

.ts code:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
this.openWebPage();
}

openWebPage() {
const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
  zoom: "no"
};

//Opening a URL and returning an InAppBrowserObject
const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(this.url, "blank", options);
}
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve your purpose with `inappbrowser` excepting rewriting native code.

Also, you cannot use embeding way like iframe. Because 'facebook' page doens't be allowed to render in `iframe`.

Then, there is only way you to get feeds from facebook. It is to **use official api** of facebook. Please visit [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/). You can get information how to use facebook api. This api allow you to fetch **data**(usually json) of your feed. And you can render the data on your way.

In the case of twitter, I think it is similiar to facebook.

Comment: thanks, I will have to use the graph-api and similar for twitter integration